# Convert seconds to Relative time

Tags: java, android, datetime, time, instant

I have been trying to make an app where I need to convert time in seconds to relative time can someone help me to do that.
example :

```
time in seconds:1594564500  
date:12 July 2020 20:05:00 GMT+05:30 
relative time: In 5 days
```

Comment: If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been trying to make an app where I need to convert time in
> seconds to relative time

A simple way is to get an object of `Instant` (say, `instant`) from the given time and then use `Instant.now().until(instant, ChronoUnit.DAYS)`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an object of Instant from the given no. of seconds
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1594564500);

        // Get the no. of days from the current time to the given time
        long days = Instant.now().until(instant, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println("No. of days: " + days);

        // ##########If you want to get date-time information##########
        // Create OffsetDateTime from Instant
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);// UTC
        System.out.println("Date-time at UTC:" + odt);
        odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));// GMT
        System.out.println("Date-time at GMT:" + odt);

        // Get LocalDateTime from OffsetDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println("Date-time without time-zone infromation: " + ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
No. of days: 5
Date-time at UTC:2020-07-12T14:35Z
Date-time at GMT:2020-07-12T15:35+01:00
Date-time without time-zone infromation: 2020-07-12T15:35
```

**Some important notes:**

1. Learn more about modern date-time API from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).
2. `LocalDateTime` drops the important information of time-zone and zone-offset from it. Choose the right date-time object from the [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) given below as per your requirement:

[image]

3. **Backport of the Java SE 8 date-time classes to Java SE 6 and 7:** check [ThreeTen-Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [How to use ThreeTenABP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

Comment: Ooooh, I like a nice chart!  Well done. A few thoughts: (a) Your title `Seconds*` has an asterisk, but I see no footnote. (b) Likewise, I see triple asterisks in the bottom row, but do not know what that indicates. (c) I suggest moving `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` together. And add a column indicating which represent a moment (a specific point on the timeline), which is just those 3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You would use something along the lines of:

```
        long timeInSeconds = 1594564500;
        long interval;
        String relative;

        long difference = Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - (timeInSeconds * 1000));

        if (difference > DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS) {
            interval = difference / DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS;
            relative = " weeks";
        } else if (difference > DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
            interval = difference / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
            relative = " days";
        } else if (difference > DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS) {
            interval = difference / DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS;
            relative = " hours";
        } else {
            interval = Long.MIN_VALUE;
            relative = "Unknown";
        }
        interval = Math.round(interval);
        Log.d("Relative Time", String.valueOf(interval) + relative);
```